# How to change dynamically created div's on hover over other element?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a text with dynamically added images. I would like to achieve that when the user hovers over the image, the word inside the text changes the background.

For example I have images with id a1, a2, a3 .... and span text with id b1, b2, b3, ... 
The goal - when the user hovers a1, the b1 span text changes background etc.

I have found this function that can be useful, but I don't know how to make it dynamic.

```
$(function() {
  $('#a').hover(function() {
  $('#b').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
  $('#b').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

Example:

```
Þeir, sem á <span class="amatic" id="b1">skipinu</span> voru, <span class="amatic" id="b2">sáu</span> ... Voru strendur hennar <span class="amatic" id="b6">háar</span> og sæbrattar

<br>
<img src="images/size_320/lod.jpg" alt="skip" id="a1">
<img src="images/size_320/videt.jpg" alt="sjá" id="a2">  
<img src="images/size_320/vlasy.jpg" alt="hár" id="a6">
```

Comment: so you just need to change background only.

Comment: I have variable amount of images - when hover over them - it changes the background of variable amount of span text. I need function that cover all hover behaviour for all images (can be 4 but also 1000).

Comment: ok then why you not create dynamic ID for all span (If you have one span where you want to hover), then after fetch ID using jQuery like,
`$('.tags').mouseover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});`
and then pass this id to your developed JS code.

Comment: I guess this is the way, but I don't know how to pass the value **1** from **a1** to function so that **b1** changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a new {attribute} for a certain element (either place that attribute on the {img} or {span}).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/33/flower-729513_960_720.jpg" id="a1" />
    <span class="text" data_current_bg="" id="text1"> Text 1 </span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/03/17/11/cosmos-flower-1712177_960_720.jpg" id="a2" />
    <span class="text" data_current_bg="" id="text2"> Text 2 </span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqysRONV6q1elD6x4WJRe_6X5oIswrNXMDByxkNkij8xPWjRECkg" id="a3" />
    <span class="text" data_current_bg="" id="text3"> Text 3 </span>
</div>
```

In this example, We assign a new attribute in the [span] element called [data_current_bg].

Then from within your JS. You can assign what value you would place for each.

```
var oWrapperImages = $('.wrapper img');

oWrapperImages.each(function() {
    // Find every {span} elements next to {img} tags
    // Assuming you set each text's bg color in css
    var oSpanTexts = $(this).parent().find('.text');

    // On loading ths js, Assign the default bg color of each texts
    var sBackgroundColor = oSpanTexts.css('background-color');
    $(this).attr('data_current_bg', sBackgroundColor);
});
```

Then you can reference this whenever you wanted to detect the 'hover' event in process

```
oWrapperImages.hover(function() {
   var oSpanTexts = $(this).parent().find('.text');
   var sCurrentBGColor = $(this).attr('data_current_bg');
   oSpanTexts.css('background-color', sCurrentBGColor);
}, function() {
   // rest of code
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for you for further reference: http://jsfiddle.net/k0o1exmf/

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

You can also assign indexes as well. In this question's case, we can change the [span] text's bg color based on their last indexes (e.g 'image1')

In this case, We will get that '1' from that image. Then append it to the text ('text').

Note that this might be a little hacky considering that you wanted to separate the [img] and [span] tags.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ozd7y8av/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it true, that in your answer the span text must follow directly the img? In that case the goal is not achieved. The images are ordered after the text.

Comment: This is for reference. You can place the [span] and [images] separately as given on your sample html and called them by reference:

var sSpanTexts = $('.span-text').attr('id'); // e.g text1
var sImages = $('.images').attr('id'); // e.g image1.

Then replace the 'text' phrase to get the numeric value '1' (e.g sSpanTexts.replace('text', '')). Then reference it for your images tags, concat it with your 'image' then the numeric value. (e.g image + 1)

Also from there, you can passed the 'color value' of your text. Up to you on how you wanted to apply it

Comment: I guess you are right. But I cannot figure out the solution from your comment. Can you narrow the answer to the question's needs?

Comment: Edited. Happy coding

Comment: It works, thank you for the edited fiddle! This code will add automatically black and white paintings to the fairy tales :) Best regards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137373/discussion-between-chejnik-and-eeya).